# PDF Viewer Origin is Different

Tags: plugins, errors, pdf

PDFf POSTER or any other pdf viewer plugin is showing an error saying that the origin is different but the pdf files are hosted on the site itself. 
[ERROR PAGE LINK](http://wmfusa.com/shop/wmf-1200f-03-1220-0200/)

Comment: The link seems to be http://secureservercdn.net/166.62.112.199/q19.8dd.myftpupload.com/wp-content/plugins/pdf-poster/pdfjs/web/viewer.php?file=http://wmfusa.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/34000.0067.pdf&download=true&print=true&openfile=false which is a different origin.

Comment: link which you kept iss not working